# Question on the base of a topology

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

So I am new to topology and I've been trying to understand the concept of a basis and am a bit stuck on this statement:
The topology $\big\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\big\}$ on the set $\{a,b\}$ has the following bases:

1.$\big\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\big\}$
2. $\big\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\big\}$

My confusion arises in the 2nd base how can $\big\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\big\}$  be a base for the topology since no unions of subsets give $\varnothing$?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The smallest base of all is $\left\{\{a\},\{b\}\right\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union of an empty collection is defined to be empty. Hence, the empty set is a union of members of any family of sets.

Comment: So the empty set in the 2nd case is the union of no elements of 2?

Comment: $Yes, exactly. @Thehomeschooler